# AMPscript update needed - If blank

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm currently using this AMPscript to handle if First Name is blank.

```
%%[ 
   VAR @firstName
   SET @firstName = AttributeValue("First Name")
]%%
%%=iif(empty(@firstName),'',@firstName)=%%, I can say...
```

This works OK if the Firstname is present, however, if it isn't it renders like this:

**, I can say...**

I need it to render like this:

**I can say...**

It only requires a tweak somewhere, but everything I've tried produces an error.

Comment: Hi. Please add examples of what you tried.

Comment: `code`%%[ 
   VAR @firstName
   SET @firstName = AttributeValue("First Name")
]%%
%%=iif(empty(@firstName),'',@firstName, )=%%, I can say...`code`

And in desperation:

`code`%%[ 
   VAR @firstName
   SET @firstName = AttributeValue("First Name")
]%%
%%=iif(empty(@firstName),'',@firstName),  =%%, I can say...`code`

Comment: You need to add the comma and the space into the firstname string using the concat function

Comment: The best way to add information to your question is to [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/290655/edit) it rather than comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

`%%=iif(empty(@firstName),'',concat(@firstName, ", "))=%%I can say...`

Answer (score 1):

I would think something like the following should work:

```
%%=iif(empty(@firstName),'', Concat(@firstName, ", "))=%%I can say...
```